# How to use comment.create & comment.delete functionalists

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

its been 2 days im keep searching for a simple code of how people
using comment.create & comment.delete functionalists that integrates with
facebook's comments plugin.

What kind of code and where i should add in my page so i take
facebook notifications in facebook when people add new comments on my website?

thank you.